# i need to get webpage code via requests, but I get a completely different code

Tags: python, python-requests

I need to login to the site using requests, but when I send a get request, the wrong thing is copied, the request content is completely different

Here is my code:

```
import requests

data = {
    "_username": "l",
    "_password": "pw"
}


headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36",
    'referer': "https://google.com"

}
url = 'https://vavadaafh.com/ru/login'

s = requests.Session()
logging = s.post(url, data=data)

f = open('result.txt','w+')
f.write(logging.text)
f.close()
```

This is what I get instead of the page code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 
    <meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer" />
    <script src="/__qrator/qauth_utm_v2.js"></script>
 
</head>
<body>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Why can't get page code? Help please

Comment: From what I see when login request is send it is send to `https://vavadaafh.com/ru/login_check` not `https://vavadaafh.com/ru/login` you should try that one as url.
Additionally as `referer` in headers pass  `https://vavadaafh.com/ru/login`

Comment: ```import requests

data = {
    "_username": "",
    "_password": ""
}


headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36",
    'referer': " https://vavadaafh.com/ru/login"

}

url = 'https://vavadaafh.com/ru/login_check'

s = requests.Session()
logging = s.post(url, data=data)

f = open('result.txt','w+')
f.write(logging.text)
f.close()```

added but same result

Comment: hmm to be honest it is really hard to trying answer this question without having working logging and password. What I would suggest is try to open this site in your browser. Open dev tools and head to `Networking` section and then look into what requests are being posted and try to recreate it

Comment: thank you!
I found the missing value for the data

Comment: but the page didn't load

Comment: I recommend you to read about HTTP request messages header https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers. I guess the server you are trying to connect to is not responding to suspicious connections. I think you can get the answer you want if you connect by putting the header data more appropriately.